# Creating edges for a riverplot

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, riverplot

I am hoping to use the riverplot package to create a flow diagram. This package needs 'edges' which are flows between levels. I want to create an edges data structure from a data frame. By way of example here is some code to create my input data.

```
rp.df<-structure(list(ID = 1:20, X1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A1", class = "factor"), 
X2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A2", 
"B2"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("A3", "B3", "C3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
table(rp.df$X1,rp.df$X2)
table(rp.df$X2,rp.df$X3)
```

with this output

```
> table(rp.df$X1,rp.df$X2)

     A2 B2
  A1 12  8
> table(rp.df$X2,rp.df$X3)

     A3 B3 C3
  A2  2  2  8
  B2  5  2  1
```

what I need is a dataframe with the flows identified in the tables, eg:

```
N1 N2 Value
A1 A2    12
A1 B2     8
A2 A3     2
A2 B3     2
A2 C3     8
B2 A3     5
B2 B3     2
B2 C3     1
```

In reality I have 10 columns of edges and 16k in flows. I have tried using reshape2 to do this but struggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base R solution, generalized for however many columns you have.

```
out <- lapply(2:(ncol(rp.df) - 1), function(i) {
  as.data.frame(table(rp.df[, i], rp.df[, i + 1]))
  }
)
setNames(do.call(rbind, out), c("N1", "N2", "Value"))
#   N1 N2 Value
# 1 A1 A2    12
# 2 A1 B2     8
# 3 A2 A3     2
# 4 B2 A3     5
# 5 A2 B3     2
# 6 B2 B3     2
# 7 A2 C3     8
# 8 B2 C3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. `select(rp.df, X1:X2)` is for the first `X` column to the one before the last `X` column. `select(rp.df, X2:X3)` is for the second `X` column to the last `X` column. By doing this you can ensure each column combination is addressed. `dat` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- map2_dfr(select(rp.df, X1:X2), 
                select(rp.df, X2:X3),
                ~as_data_frame(table(.x, .y))) %>%
  set_names(c("N1", "N2", "Value"))
dat
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#   N1    N2    Value
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 A1    A2       12
# 2 A1    B2        8
# 3 A2    A3        2
# 4 B2    A3        5
# 5 A2    B3        2
# 6 B2    B3        2
# 7 A2    C3        8
# 8 B2    C3        1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here are two `data.table` solutions.

The first one binds the node data into one large data object first and aggregates, finally. The second aggregates for each combination of columns and binds the totals, finally.

#### Bind node data then aggregate

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(rp.df)
edges <- lapply(3:ncol(rp.df), 
       function(i) rp.df[, .SD, .SDcols = (i-1L):i]) %>% 
  rbindlist() %>% 
  .[, .(Value = .N), by = .(N1 = X1, N2 = X2 )]
edges
```

> ```
>    N1 N2 Value
> 1: A1 A2    12
> 2: A1 B2     8
> 3: A2 A3     2
> 4: A2 B3     2
> 5: A2 C3     8
> 6: B2 A3     5
> 7: B2 B3     2
> 8: B2 C3     1
> ```

#### Aggregate node data then bind

```
nm <- names(rp.df) %>% stringr::str_subset("^X")
edges <- lapply(2:length(nm), 
                function(i) rp.df[, .N, by = c(nm[i-1], nm[i])]) %>%
  rbindlist() 
setnames(edges, c("N1", "N2", "Value"))
edges
```

> ```
>    N1 N2 Value
> 1: A1 A2    12
> 2: A1 B2     8
> 3: A2 A3     2
> 4: A2 B3     2
> 5: A2 C3     8
> 6: B2 A3     5
> 7: B2 B3     2
> 8: B2 C3     1
> ```

#### Caveat

Note that both approaches are not fully equivalent in case some edges appear multiple times. (They are equivalent for the given sample dataset).

Let's assume the edge `(A1, A2)` appears in `X1` and `X2` and also in `X2` and `X3`. The first approach will summarize this in one output row while the second approach will create two output rows. So, the second approach would need an additional aggregation step to produce the same result as the first approach.

Which approach is suitable has to be decided by the OP.

If it is required, the stage or level where an edge is occuring can be recorded as well:

```
nm <- names(rp.df) %>% stringr::str_subset("^X")
edges <- lapply(2:length(nm), 
                function(i) rp.df[, .N, by = c(nm[i-1], nm[i])]) %>%
  rbindlist(idcol = TRUE) 
setnames(edges, c("Level", "N1", "N2", "Value"))
edges

   Level N1 N2 Value
1:     1 A1 A2    12
2:     1 A1 B2     8
3:     2 A2 A3     2
4:     2 A2 B3     2
5:     2 A2 C3     8
6:     2 B2 A3     5
7:     2 B2 B3     2
8:     2 B2 C3     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the caveat. This does not apply in my case but might in others, so well worth mentioning.